# What is the/one correct approach to use a concatenated value in the setText() method of a button?

Tags: java, android, string, concatenation

I try to use a concatenated value to set the text of a button, because `int xp;` is calculated at runtime.
The only approach that works throws a warning and is maybe bad practice.

Do you have any idea about a better solution?

I´ve tried it in these ways:

---

**1st approach:**

```
public class selectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Serializable {

    private int xp = 2000;
    public int getXp(){
            return xp;
        }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    Button currentXp1 = findViewById(R.id.currentXp1);

    currentXp1.setText(R.string.praefixXP + String.valueOf(getXp())); }
}
```

**Result:**

Compiles but assigns an int / numeric value to the Button.

---

**2nd approach:**

```
public class selectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Serializable {

    private int xp = 2000;
    public int getXp(){
            return xp;
        }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    Button currentXp1 = findViewById(R.id.currentXp1);

    currentXp1.setText(R.string.praefixXP + (getXp()));}
}
```

**Result:**

Throws a Resources$NotFoundException.

---

**3rd approach:**

```
public class selectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Serializable {

    private int xp = 2000;
    public int getXp(){
            return xp;
        }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    Button currentXp1 = findViewById(R.id.currentXp1);

    currentXp1.setText("XP: " + (getXp())); }
}
```

**Result:**

Works, but needs a annotation:

```
@SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n"})
```

---

**4th approach:**

```
public class selectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Serializable {

private int xp = 2000;
public int getXp(){
        return xp;
    }

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

Button currentXp1 = findViewById(R.id.currentXp1);

currentXp1.setText(getResources().getIdentifier("praefixXP", "string", getPackageName()) + getXp());}
}
```

**Result:**

Throws a Resources$NotFoundException.

---

*strings.xml:*

```
<resources>

    <string name="praefixXP">XP: </string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
   currentXp1.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.praefixXP)+getXp()));
```

To get string value from the String resource file we need to use `getResources().getString(STRING_ID)` and in this case, I'm just concatenating the result of getXp() with the value of the string.

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear**

Comment: Using currentXp1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.praefixXP),getXp()); throws an error message: 

error: no suitable method found for setText(String,int),           
method TextView.setText(CharSequence,BufferType) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to BufferType)
    method TextView.setText(int,BufferType) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to int)

Comment: what is the return type of getXp()

Comment: Try to use       currentXp1.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.praefixXP)+getXp()));

Comment: Great, it´s working now! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help you.